# WP Loop. If featured image is a panorama (3:1 ratio) execute some code

Tags: loop, post-thumbnails

I'm wondering if there is a way to write a condition (if/else) for a featured image. If user submits a featured image in 3:1 ratio (panorama, one edge is 3 times longer than the other edge) - execute some code like this:

```
if( featured_img_is_panorama() ) { echo "featured img is panorama" }
```

All this in the loop of course. I added support for featured image (aka `post_thumbnails`) in the `functions.php`. Any help/clue pointing in the right direction much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is untested, but should be a step in the right direction:

#### within the loop:

```
//get url of featured image
$atts = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()));

if ($atts) { //if an image was found
  $width = $atts[1];
  $height = $atts[2];
  if ($width / $height > 3) {
    echo "is at least 3 times wider than it is tall";
  }
}
```

- [WP: get_post_thumbnail_id() »](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id)
- [WP: wp_get_attachment_image_src() »](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src)

(old links, used in original answer)

- [PHP: getimagesize() »](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)
- [WP: wp_get_attachment_url() »](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url)

Thanks to [Pat J](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/16121/pat-j) for the tip about wp_get_attachment_image_src(). Much, much better.

Comment: You could make your life easier with [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src), which returns an array containing the image URL, width, height, and a `boolean` indicating whether the image has been resized.

Comment: Had to turn off error reporting becouse it was echoing out notices, but besides that worked like a charm! Big thanks @PatJ & @BenjaminLove!